# JDO: How to make a detached object transient?

Tags: persistence, jdo, datanucleus, transient

I'm using DataNucleus 2 JDO implementation. I have a detached object that i must attach, BUT i don't want to attach ALL the fields (in this case, a collection)

```
public class Obj {
    private String key;
    private Collection<String> col;
}
```

Is there a reason why it is not possible to do this:

```
tx.begin();
obj.makeTransientAll(obj.getCol()); // Do not persist
pm.makePersistent(obj);
tx.commit();
```

or REFRESH from the database:

```
tx.begin();
obj.refreshAll(obj.getCol()); // Discard any changes
pm.makePersistent(obj);
tx.commit();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should apply your changes **AFTER** refreshing your object or making it transient.
Or on the other hand, do something I really wanted to do to understand more how `JDO` works but I didn't have much time to investigate. Why don't you after initially looking up your object, do not detach it, but keep it in attached state and modify outside the look up method, then make it persistence in another method ?

What confuses me here is that in the look up method, you'll not close your `PersistenceManager` and in the latter method that saves your object you'll be using another `PersistenceManager` which is ought to fire an exception because you are managing an object using a different `PersistenceManager` other than the one that looked it up on the first place.

I'm still learning about `JDO` and `Datanucleus` so please expect that my suggest may not work. And sharing your experience with my suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: If you don't detach you cannot change it outside a transaction. The idea is to change it, but DISCARD some fields before makePersistent. In the examples i gave, i'm applying the changes after a refresh...